# How to specify a type family with multiparameter injectivity?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-constraints, type-families

I have a typeclass `A` with a non injective associated type `Context`

```
class A a where
   type Context a
```

so many instances of `A` can have the same `Context`.

Some instances of `A` are also instances of the class `AA`, that has two additional associated types, `B` and `C`.

```
class (A a) => AA a where
   type B a
   type C a
   problematic :: Context a -> B a -> C a -> a
```

The intention is that given a `Context`, the combination of `B a` and `C a` uniquely identify `a`, but I don't know how to express this.

I know it's possible to make constraints like

```
class A a where
   type B a = b | b -> a
```

, but what I need is some kind of constraint with multiple parameters, like `(Context a, B a, C a) -> a`. How can this be achieved?

Comment: While I overwhelmingly prefer type families, this might be a case where it's simpler to use functional dependencies instead (or perhaps both type families and fundeps).

Comment: I see, this actually came up as I'm doing a rewrite of an old project, in part to reduce the use of multiparameter typeclasses to clean up the API type signatures. Maybe I can find some compromise.

Answer (score 4):

This neat solution was posted by Edward Kmett on reddit.

```
class A a where
  type Context a

class (A a, Context a ~ ctx, B a ~ b, C a ~ b,) => AA' a ctx b c | a -> ctx b c, ctx b c -> a where
  type B a 
  type C a

type AA a = AA' a (Context a) (B a) (C a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could return a pair. I haven't tested this, but it would look something like this:

```
type family Fst a where Fst '(a, b) = a
type family Snd a where Snd '(a, b) = b
type B a = Fst (BC a)
type C a = Snd (BC a)

class A a => AA a where
    type BC a = b | b -> a
```

You may need some kind signatures in there to give the type checker a hint; the compile-time-level version of the type checker tends to monomorph its types a bit earlier than the runtime-level one.

Comment: That's an interesting approach, but assuming it works, it only solves part of the problem. `Context a` is not determined, so `a` would still be ambiguous in `problematic`.